# I want to create a dynamic variable in vb6

Tags: dynamic, vb6

My code-

```
For i= 1 to 10
str & i = InputBox("Enter a number")
Next i
```

The problem is that it does not create the variable and highlights the "&" sign. Please help. 
P.S. I dont want to use an array.

**Edit** (Updated requirement from one of the comments):

I can't use an array because its for a school project and i'm not allowed, and the user can enter as many numbers as he wants to, so..?

Comment: so there is no way i can do this? i mean without an array

Comment: No. And even if there was a way, you really do not want to take this approach. Dynamic variables are always a code smell. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can use a Collection, which is a similar approach as the array, but maybe that is allowed in your school project.

Comment: +1 for using an ampersand instead of the plus sign to concatenate your string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marco says, you can't have variable variables.

Sounds like you need an array instead:

```
dim inputs(1 To 10) as Integer
For i= 1 to 10
    inputs(i) = InputBox("Enter a number")
Next i
```

UPDATE: Answering requirements of unknown number of inputs, and absence of arrays:

You can possibly use a collection, as this will take new inputs as you require:

```
'Create a collection and a temp variable
Dim strs As New Collection
Dim str As String

'Loop until the input is empty
Do
    str = InputBox("Enter a number")
    If str <> "" Then strs.Add (str)
Loop Until str = ""


'Then later you can do
Dim val As String
For Each val In strs
    'Do something with val
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You say the user can enter as many numbers as they want. Maybe you don't want a `For` loop then, rather a `Do` or `While` loop that you `Exit` when the user is done (when they leave the input box blank or type "done" or something).

But also, you probably don't need to store all the numbers at once. Just input the number into a single variable, do whatever processing you need to do with it inside the loop body (e.g., add it to a total), and then reuse the same variable name on the next iteration of the loop.

If you really need to store them all at once, yes, you'd need an array (or a Dictionary or Collection object, but still, they're like arrays).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a dynamic variable in VB6

This is what you *think* you want, but it certainly is not what you need.

You might use an array for this:

```vb
Dim str(10) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i= 1 to UBound(str)
  str(i) = InputBox("Enter a number")
Next i
```

If there is no upper limit, you could use a collection.

```vb
Dim str As New Collection

Do
  str.Add InputBox("Enter a number"), CStr(str.Count)
Loop Until str(str.Count) = ""

str.Remove str.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what the poster is trying to do has been misread. They want to use a single variable but continue to update it with additional user input. A VB string will work nicely for this and appending a vbCrLf would make splitting the string to separate the value easy. This is very similar to Tomalak's sample.

```
Dim strUserInput As String

Do
   strUserInput = InputBox("Enter a number")
   Text1.Text = Text1.Text & vbCrLf & strUserInput   'I am displaying the user input but another string can be used here also
Loop While Len(strUserInput) > 0
```

Comment: Please never use strings for storing non string data!

Comment: @Deanna What other kind of data do you get from an InputBox? This would be string representations of (expected) numbers.

Comment: Yes, but you're not storing data in an `InputBox`. Convert its native type to and from a string for display, but be careful of localisation. Using the native type also does soem form of sanitisation.